# mocking a function call in midje

Tags: testing, clojure, stubbing, redefinition, midje

Say I have a function

```
(defn extenal_api_fn [stuff]
   ... do things....
)

(defn register_user [stuff]
  (external_api_fn stuff))
```

And then a test

```
(def stuff1
  {:user_id 123 })

(def stuff2
  {:user_id 234})

(background (external_api_fn stuff1) => true
            (with-redefs [external_api_fn (fn [data] (println "mocked function"))]
            (register_user stuff1) => true)
            (register_user stuff2) => true)

(facts "stuff goes here"
  (fact "user that registers correctly
    (= 1 1) => truthy)
  (fact "user that has a registration failure"
    (= 1 2) => falsy))
```

This fails with

```
"you never said #'external_api_fn" would be called with these arguments:
    contents of stuff1
```

What would be a good way to stub this function call (in only some cases) in order to simulate an internal transaction failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Midje's `provided`:

```
(fact
  (register_user stuff1) => :registered
  (provided
    (extenal_api_fn stuff1) => :registered))

(fact
  (register_user stuff2) => :error
  (provided
    (external_api_fn stuff2) => :error))
```

You can also stub a function to return a value no matter input parameters by using `anything` in place of the function argument:

```
(fact
  (register_user stuff2) => :error
  (provided
    (external_api_fn anything) => :error))
```